# Json decode and again json encode not return same value

Tags: java, php, json

I have a JSON string (Created through JAVA). I can decode(PHP : json_decode) and create(PHP:json_encode) again JSON string but the return cant the same as an original JSON string. hash256 value not return same value.

```
$Requestbody = "{\"billerid\": \"RELENG\",\"short_name\": \"HOME91\", 
\"authenticators\": [{\"parameter_name\": \"Consumer number\",\"value\": 
\"155555105\"}],\"customer\": {\"customer_name\": \"OG 
Test\",\"customer_mobile\": \"1231231234\",\"customer_email\": 
\"agtest1@Testcomny.com\",\"customer_pan\": \"AEPM123RC4\",\"customer_aadhaar\": 
\"123123123123\"},\"metadata\": {\"agent\": {\"agentid\": 
\"BD001MPY100000100001\",\"sub_agentid\": \"BD001MPY11\"},\"device\": 
{\"mobile\": \"9800000000\",\"geocode\": \"19.075984,72.877656\",\"postal_code\": 
\"400053\",\"ip\": \"124.124.1.1\",\"channel\": \"INT\",\"branchCode\": 
\"UTI00030\",\"terminalid\": \"123123\",\"imei\": \"123123123\",\"mac\": \"11-AC-
58-21-1B-AA\",\"os\": \"iOS\",\"app\": \"AGENTAPP\",\"user_agent\": 
\"Mozilla\",\"dvc_fngrprnt\": \"AB22331DF49A\"}}}";
```

Comment: What does the original source look like?

Comment: Do they have the same meaning, though? JSON doesn't have a unique or even canonical representation, multiple different strings can encode the same value; for example, there can be additional spaces, tabs or newlines (of any kind) in many different places in the JSON.

Comment: see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php second parameter the default options for JSON encode for java and php is difference

Comment: Hi, can you add a dump of your re-encoded json ?

Comment: Yes @MatthieuBesson

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string contains spaces after a few colons. If these are removed, the strings after json_decode and json_encode are even the same.

```
$Requestbody = "{\"billerid\": \"RELENG\",\"short_name\": \"HOME91\",\"authenticators\": [{\"parameter_name\": \"Consumer number\",\"value\":\"155555105\"}],\"customer\": {\"customer_name\": \"OGTest\",\"customer_mobile\": \"1231231234\",\"customer_email\":\"agtest1@Testcomny.com\",\"customer_pan\": \"AEPM123RC4\",\"customer_aadhaar\":\"123123123123\"},\"metadata\": {\"agent\": {\"agentid\":\"BD001MPY100000100001\",\"sub_agentid\": \"BD001MPY11\"},\"device\":{\"mobile\": \"9800000000\",\"geocode\": \"19.075984,72.877656\",\"postal_code\":\"400053\",\"ip\": \"124.124.1.1\",\"channel\": \"INT\",\"branchCode\":\"UTI00030\",\"terminalid\": \"123123\",\"imei\": \"123123123\",\"mac\": \"11-AC-58-21-1B-AA\",\"os\": \"iOS\",\"app\": \"AGENTAPP\",\"user_agent\":\"Mozilla\",\"dvc_fngrprnt\": \"AB22331DF49A\"}}}";

$arr = json_decode($Requestbody, true);
$str = json_encode($arr);

$cleanStr = str_replace(': ',':',$Requestbody);
var_dump($cleanStr === $str);//bool(true)
```

However, how @sabik correctly writes in the comment, Json strings cannot normally be compared.

In contrast to this, arrays created with json_decode ($str, true) can be compared directly.